# Using CiviCRM to create robust volunteer system

Tags: civivolunteer

I'm looking to create a robust volunteer system that includes training, tracking of hours, marketing to attract volunteers and cultivate existing ones, and an app for volunteers to be able to log in and out after their session.  Is this the right platform to use to build from?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if CiviCRM could be used as a framework by your software development team to create such an app?
Or are you asking if CiviCRM already *is* such an app that you can pull off the shelf and use as-is for those needs?

Comment: Every time we as a Non-Profit org with a small development team make a decision how to base a new app around customer or people relationships with some CRM needs and maybe event management the only question that may lead away from CiviCRM is performance. Serving millions of visitors is not civicrm's purpose. So I would say, yes, if you answer coleman's question with option "A (Build yourself)" and you have some dev skills aboard than CiviCRM should be a good choice.

Comment: I'd say the guts of this are totally do-able in CiviCRM. For the training component I think I would be using a Drupal integration as CiviCRM is not really suited to content delivery of training courses. With Drupal you can combine your CiviCRM and Drupal training data. For training consider the Drupal H5P module. I'm not particularly au fait with app development but that seems a rather expensive option compared to a well-designed mobile first website.